# xcode: can't see in storyboard a navigation item

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I have added to my `tableView` with `navigationController` a bar button with text "Start!".
[image]

But I can not see it anymore in the storyboard.

In my build I can see it:

[image]

I think this is also the reason for this error log message:

**pushViewController:animated: called on  while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.**

What can I do to make the bar button visible again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tableviewcontroller is covering the navbar in your storyboard. Check the properties in the storyboard and verify that your tableviewcontroller is inheriting his geometry. (setting is called inferred)

[image]